# Build a project that reports if a point is inside a restricted area

Tags: python, geometry, google-earth, api, maps

I want to build a project that can accuse if a point is inside a restricted area or not. For this I have to use an map with restricted areas already delimited by layers and the entry point is a geographic coordinate.

[image]

To do this project in **Python**, I'm thinking of using the "**shapely.geometry**" library to convert the whole map into a Cartesian plane with the constrained areas delimited. In this sense, I have to convert the geographic coordinates into Cartesian coordinates (x,y).

Does anyone know of any library that allows converting geographic coordinates to Cartesian coordinates?

Or by any chance, does anyone know a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Shapely** is a library well adapted for what you want to do, in particular for checking if a Polygon contains a Point.
2. You don't **need** to convert the coordinates, but you need to make sure that both Point and Polygon geometries are using the same coordinate system (if not you need to convert one of them either way).

Assuming they are in the same system, you need to make objects for:

- your restricted areas polygons
- your point(s)
- and then use the polygon.contains() shapely method

For instance:

```
polygon = geometry.polygon([[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [0, 0]]) # with your own coordinates

point = geometry.Point(0.5, 0.5) # with you own coordinates

within = polygon.contains(point) # boolean indicating if the point is within the polygon or not
```

Comment: Kasper, thank you very much for your help.

Now I have a trivial question but it has given me a lot of headache. In my database, the coordinates are in the following formatting: (((X1 Y1, X2 Y2))).

Is there any function in Pandas that lets you change the parentheses to square brackets and add the commas to follow the shapely.geometry syntax?

(((X1 Y2))) -> ([[X1, Y1], [X2, Y2]])

Comment: I cannot tell for the Panda methods in details. I would recommend you to first convert data extracted from your DB to WKT formats, which look close to the ones you already have. A WKT polygon is: 'POLYGON (X1 Y1,X2 Y2,..., Xn Yn)'. If you use Pandas to replace '(((' by 'POLYGON(' and ')))' by ')', it should work. Once you have your coordinates as WKT (which are string), you can create shapely objects with the shapely.wkt.loads() function : polygon = shapely.wkt.loads(your_polygon_string). Same for : point = shapely.wkt.loads(your_point_string). From there, polygon.contains(point) will work.